# Print glossary entry in acronym and long form

Tags: glossaries

Is there a way to have a word listed in the glossary in its acronym AND long form?

**LED** light-emitting diode

**light-emitting diode** A semiconductor light source.

I tried with two entries, but it doesn't seem right.. and is problematic with respect to the number list.

```
\newglossaryentry{light-emitting diode}
{
  name={light-emitting diode},
  description={A semiconductor light source}
}

\newacronym{led}{LED}{\gls{light-emitting diode}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want a combination of glossary and acronym list. How about typesetting your entry this way?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{LED}{%
  name={LED},
  first={light-emitting diode (LED)},
  description={Light-emitting diode -- a semiconductor light source},
}

\textheight=80pt% just for the example

\begin{document}

Some text about \gls{LED}.

Some more text about \gls{LED}.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There are two issues with this solution: how do I refer to the long form without resetting the first use flag? For acronyms there's \acrlong (useful if a word hasn't been used for a while or for emphasis). And also, I'd like a separate entry because someone looking for "Light-emitting diode" in the alphabetically ordered list will find nothing. For a long glossary of very specialized terminology this can be annoying (especially in printed form).